# Magento Connect: cannot connect to the host

Tags: magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

Managing a site in Magento, Magento Connect Manager after login takes me to this error:

> cannot connect to the host
>   magento.*nameofthesite*.*domain-owned-by-old-maintainer*

The site has been moved from one host to another one and the old developer has been changed

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the `/downloader/cache.cfg` file and `/downloader/.cache` folder after changing URLs

Comment: what should it be the new url?

Comment: By running `mage mage-setup .` it will reset the URL